# Page without a URL?

Tags: url

When I open a new google sheet, I see this page:

[image: webpage without a URL, showing "about:blank" in the browser's address bar]

Note that the URL is "about:blank" even though there is content.  How is this possible?  What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Page without a URL?**
>
> When I open a new google sheet, I see this page.
>
> Note that the URL is "about:blank" even though there is content. **How
>   is this possible? What's going on?**

See below for how this is possible and what is probably going on and what to do to try to correct.

> [**How do I remove
>   about:blank?**](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/about-blank-removal/)
>
> About:blank is a special page within most browsers (Internet Explorer,
>   Firefox or Google Chrome), and it does nothing more than display a
>   blank page.
>
> Although most major web browsers feature a default website to which
>   the browser re-directs you at start-up, corrupted profile data can
>   instead cause your Web browser to display a blank page with the
>   subject “about:blank” on the URL bar.
>
> Let’s be clear about something, about:blank is not malware. However,
>   occasionally, malware will explicitly mess with your web browser
>   settings and about:blank will be displayed. Browser hijackers will
>   sometimes change the homepage of your browser, and when your antivirus
>   will not correctly clean-up the infection, it might corrupt the
>   settings. In cases like these, the browser will simply displays
>   about:blank page.
>
> Getting rid of the about:blank page is fairly easy, and can be done by
>   manually editing the URL startup page into the “Home Page” section
>   your web browser.
>
> So about:blank it can appear due to browser issues (corrupt data),
>   malware (browser hijackers, adware or potentially unwanted programs),
>   or if there’s been malware that has not been properly removed.
>
> If you suspect that your computer might be infected with malware
>   (adware, browser hijacker or any other type of malware) or simply want
>   to restore your browser settings to its default, you can follow the
>   below guide.

*See [**here**](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/about-blank-removal/#browser) for steps for removing **About:Blank** with Chrome, Internet Explorer, or Firefox—pick the appropriate tab the your web browser and follow those instruction in STEP1 that'll guide you to resetting the browser settings if it's likely just a web browser setting issue. If you suspect malware, etc. chaning your settings, you can likely go right to STEP4 and use [**Malwarebytes Anti-Malware**](https://www.malwarebytes.org/antimalware/) as the next option and do a full scan with your updated AV.*